# Limit the cell value in excel

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, calculator

I was wondering if it is a way to limit a cell to a value.

I am calculating frome numbers, and i want to only display the maximum of 3850 but also if the input value is lower i want that number instead.

Exemlpe:

```
A1 = input number
A2 = A1*1,2%
A3 = A2*12
A4 = <<<<------ This value need to be 3850 and if it is under 3850 i want this as the value instead.
A5 = A4*25%
A6 = SUM
```

i have tried different solutions but i can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use MIN():

```
=MIN(A3,3850)
```

Now the max allowed is 3850

Comment: used ; instead of ,

Comment: @MarcelNygårdMossige If that is what your local settings need then yes.  Mine is `,`